# Best compression method for 200gb fixed .vhd

Tags: compression

I have a clone of my laptop's hdd saved in the ".vhd" format, as I am going to install the 
Windows 20H1 Insider release from .iso soon. I have saved it in the fixed format at 200gb exactly through drive management. I would like to fit this file on a ~64GB Sandisk Ultra USB 3.0 flash drive. I have seen advice to use 7zip, but I am not sure if it will compress the file so it will fit on my USB drive. I am not sure if compression at this scale is even possible, but I am hopeful.

EDIT: The .vhd file is for backup purposes only.

EDIT #2: I'm dumb. The .vhd file is about 1/2 the size I anticipated. ~110gb.

Comment: You need a bigger drive.  What you want is not possible

Answer (score 2):

It's dubious you will be able to get a 1/3 reduction by compression even when selecting the maximal compression available in [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/), with multiple CPUs, solid mode, Ultra, 96 MB of dictionary size, and 255 byte word size. Therefore, a larger USB flash drive, a larger external drive, or using two USB flash drives  consecutively may be required.

Plain text will compress down as much as 90%, but you're going to have a lot of code. Code's often already compressed, and compressing a compressed file only gets you an 1-3% improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Use a USB Hard or SSD Drive that has adequate capacity. This will be a better solution than a USB Key and will not saddle you with the limit of  your USB Key.